# Span chart series across multiple charts. SSRS Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder

I have a report which contains input parameters "Server Groups" and "Servers"
The report displays a number of performance metrics (in chart form). Each metric has it's own chart and data is obtained via a SCOM database.

The problem I'm having is that some server groups contain many servers usually over 10 which makes plotting data on a chart (+10 Series) very cluttered and difficult to read.

Is there a feature within Report Builder 3.0 that will generate a second chart and plot series # 6-10 and a third chart for series # 11-15 and so on?

I've looked at placing the chart in a matrix and also using multiple chart areas but haven't been able to find a solution.

Can anyone suggest a solution, perhaps there is a expression I could use?

Thanks

=================================

OK, I had put this issue aside for some time but now I had to revisit it. It still remains unresolved but I think I'm getting closer.

I can place the charts in a table and then group the table by the series data (servers). This will give me one series (server) per chart. I can also use this expression... =Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/10)
which would work if I wanted to generate a new chart per X number lines retrieved from the database. The problem is there are many multiple lines of data per series because there is a date component to the data retrieved.

Can anyone suggest an expression that might fit my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

One thought is to put your chart inside a list. Then you would need to add a column to your results that assigns the group. I'm not sure the best way to do that for your dataset, but if you can find a way to come up with a ranking of your servers from 1 to n, and then use a case statement to assign  servers 1-5 to group 1, 6-10 to group 2, etc. Then your list can use this server grouping. The rendered reprot will show a chart containing data for each server grouping separately.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt response.
I will have a play around with the list feature, something I've not used before, and see if I can get it working.